# Eclipse: Failed to create java virtual machine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I tried looking answers on stack but nine of them helped so I asked it again. I installed windows 8.1 and downloaded latest version of adt bundle. Whenever I try opening eclipse it gives me error "Failed to create Java virtual machine". The solutions provided on stack says to reduce xmx from 1024 to 512. But my ini file is already in that format. Dont know what to do. PLease help.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: Solution Is to delete "-XX:MaxPermSize=512M"  this line. But can anyone explain why??